# ubuntu 12.04 pxe boot fail with message "IP-Config: no response after *** secs - give up"

Tags: boot, networking, dhcp, pxe

I followed the DisklessUbuntuHowto and set up my pxe boot service. When configure the dhcp server in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`, I tried to use static IP address as follows, in which "00:22:15:F8:D9:1A" is the mac address of the first network card in sms04 (it has two).

```
allow booting;
allow bootp;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.0.21 192.168.0.30;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
  option routers 192.168.0.50;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.50;

  filename "/pxelinux.0";
}

host sms04 {
  hardware ethernet 00:22:15:F8:D9:1A;
  fixed-address 192.168.0.25;
}
```

When I boot sms04 using the first network card, it can successfully get the IP 192.168.0.25 (static ip) and then load vmlinuz and initrd.

[image]

And then it failed with message `IP-Config: no response after * secs - give up`

[image]

Now, I try to pull out the cable in my first network card and plug in the second, after a while, it successfully boot up with dynamic IP address 192.168.0.21!

However, the dynamic IP address is unwanted. I try every method to boot from static IP, by failed.

I will appreciate any reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a lot of time in this problem. So today I fixed it. Try to edit /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf and change:
DEVICE=
to
DEVICE=eth0

See ya.

Comment: I fixed this problem by plug the cable into another network card (there were two network cards). However, there still existed several problems such as all computer had the same host name, and i have turn to the traditional boot up method.

Comment: Any way, thanks for you reply, and I hope it could help other people.

Comment: Yay, thanks, I've been bashing away at this one for a day until I found this.  I could get static IP working but never DHCP, found several useless other suggestions but your's was the right one.